# Need a better design for my database schema, make change request value of a specific row, column in a table

Tags: database, database-design, database-schema

I have a case where I would like to make a change request for a specific field on a table, where there will be two parties one that makes the change request of specific field and the other one that accepts it.

Let's assume for now I have this table called 'Deals' with current fields as:

```
deals: investor_id, team_invested_id , investment_size, investment_type , pmv, etc...
```

Now both can make request for a change for any of the attributes on table and the request has to be approved by the each other.

My solution so far is this, but I do doubt on this:
Make new table 'deals_change_requests' with fields as:

```
deals_change_requests: id, deal_id, team_requested_id, column_name, new_value, approved.
```

This might work well, but it forces me to treat all the attributes of deals the same type format... cz I should decide only one type for new_value attribute and that should be VARCHAR so far I have seen...

Any better solution, idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest baking this into the main table:

```
investor_id, team_invested_id , investment_size, investment_type , pmv, version, approved, team_requested_id
          1,                1,             1000,             BOND,  11,       0,        1,                 1
          1,                1,             1000,             BOND,  13,       1,        0,                 2
```

In the example above, there is an investment created by team 1, with a PMV of 11, and it's approved. There's also a change request from team 2, changing the PMV to 13, but it's not yet approved.

This means you don't have to mess around with data types, and all the change history lives in the same table. You can obviously include dates to show when the changes became effective.

Comment: I like your solution, just wondering, how would I Update a deal later let say from Admin, since you have many records for the same deal between two parties, I guess that would become complex somehow?

I also see when I should display the deal, I should check for the latest version where approved is 1, right?

I just want to make sure before I start to do so...

Comment: One more thing I noticed, if I want to make change request for only one attribute, I should always get all other attribute from the latest deal approved with the new change... This is a bit extra work, doesn't it feel so?

Comment: ok I am accepting your answer, eventhou I decided to go with my current solution i described above, I can't do your solution now bc it will cost me to change my previous code if I re-structure like you said. I should probably had to think about this case at the beginning and do so like your design... With the current solution i'v come i dont need to change my previous code.